# All objects suddenly created with animations

Tags: objects, duplicate

I have changed some setting in Blender 4.0.2 that results in that all objects (created or duplicated) now suddenly includes an animation.

I have a simple scene and deleted all keyframes (I do not want any animations), but when I create a new object or duplicate an existing one (without any animations) then the result is a new object including an animation that I have to delete.

Comment: Hello could you please share the object you're trying to duplicate?

Comment: auto keying is activated, maybe.

Comment: @lemon: Auto Keying was enabled - now it works perfectly. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto keying is activated. Turn it off.